# PL/SQL Statement ignored , SQL Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am trying to build a web with tomcat 8.5. And connected the database with it too.

I have defined the procedure with SQL in order to insert some data from the web to database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE applyInsert02(cid IN VARCHAR2
                                         ,cidno IN NUMBER
                                         ,sid IN VARCHAR2
                                         ,aid IN VARCHAR2
                                         ,weeknum IN VARCHAR2
                                         ,pstatus IN VARCHAR2
                                         ,isprocessed IN VARCHAR2
                                         ,result OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
  nCnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  result:='';

  INSERT INTO processed (c_id
                        ,c_id_no
                        ,s_id
                        ,a_id
                        ,week_num
                        ,p_status
                        ,is_processed)
  values (cid
         ,cidno
         ,sid
         ,aid
         ,weeknum
         ,p_status
         ,isprocessed);
  COMMIT;
  result:="done.";
END;
```

And this is how I made PROCESSED entity beforehand.

```
CREATE TABLE processed(c_id      VARCHAR2(10)
                      ,c_id_no   NUMBER(1)
                      ,s_id      VARCHAR2(10)
                      ,a_id      VARCHAR2(10)
                      ,week_num  VARCHAR2(10)
                      ,p_status  VARCHAR2(10)
                      ,is_processed VARCHAR2(10)
                      ,CONSTRAINT pro_pk PRIMARY KEY (c_id,c_id_no,s_id,a_id)
                      ,CONSTRAINT p_a_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (s_id,c_id,c_id_no,a_id) REFERENCES attendance(s_id,c_id,c_id_no,a_id)
);
```

This is the error I have:

> 8/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   8/119    PL/SQL: ORA-00984:
>   10/1     PL/SQL: Statement ignored

It has told me the lines and columns but I cannot figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors:

```
    weeknum,
    pstatus,            --> not p_status
    isprocessed
  );

  COMMIT;
  result := 'done.';    --> single quotes, not double
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I don't know why it is so hard to find errors on my own.